# Why is "evil" such a taboo word in English conversations?

Tags: offensive-language

> [evil](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evil_2) (noun):
>
> [uncountable] a force that causes bad things to happen; morally bad
>   behaviour.
>
> [evil](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/evil_1?q=evil) (adjective):
>
> having a harmful effect on people; morally bad
>
> extremely unpleasant

(OLD)

That's a very readable definition with a very wide range of applicability. Seemingly, anybody who takes actions (intentionally) that lead to bad things, can be deemed evil. I have looked at other definitions, and the pattern holds: it's just a term to describe people who do morally bad stuff.

And yet, whenever I use the word 'evil' (to describe someone, i.e. "they are evil") in a discussion with natural English speakers, I am almost always deemed unserious and immature, and my remark inflammatory and inappropriate... that's to be expected at times, but the issue is that this happens *even if the others agree that the person in question does morally bad things!*

I have noticed that if I use a word other than *evil*, but still with the same definition, I am not going to get into any sort of trouble. For example if I said

> They are amoral.

or

> They are cruel.

nobody would bat an eye. Yet the word "evil" (which most dictionaries list as a possible synonym to "amoral" and "cruel") makes everybody lose their mind.

Why are these people so scared of using their own words?

Comment: Maybe because they are judicial, and being native speakers they understand the implications and connotations far better than you do.

Comment: @Josh I don't think *evil* is a taboo word in the slightest, an evil person suggests someone who is *intrinsically* wicked, to their very core.  An evil person  consciously and willfully embraces acts of wrongdoing and does not shy away from acts of misdeeds. Acts of cruelty can be justified by their perpetrators, but not acts of evil. To kill an innocent person, for personal gain, is cruel and heartless, but to do it deliberately, for "fun", is an act of *evilness*.

Comment: You’ve cherry-picked _some_ of the definitions given and ignored others. That’s the essential answer to your question. Take a closer look at the examples under the definitions that you quote from OLD: #1 (“enjoying harming others; morally bad and cruel”) is the only one with an example describing people and personal traits. #2 and #4 which you quote here are only used to describe deeds, effects, and smells in the examples. That’s no coincidence. Describing an act as evil is **not the same** as describing a _person_ as evil. An evil person is much, much worse than an evil act.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Everyone plays this game a different way. From his astronomical reputation score, I'm guessing Josh is trying to play the *perfect* game of EL&U: no downvotes on his posts, top answer when he can get it, etc. maybe he also refrains from downvoting himself in order to preserve as much rep as he can? But then again he does post a lot of bounties. Who knows? I find his quest for perfection kinda endearing, personally.

Comment: @DanBron *pfft*... deletes perfectly good, well-referenced answers. If he wants an unblemished reputation, but I don't think it's that,  then he should post community wiki posts.

Comment: Sak, it's not that the word *evil* is taboo, but your use of it seems inappropriate... 

That happens even if the others agree that the person in question does morally bad things simply because *morally bad*

A lying, murdering thief doesn't have to be evil, nor anything like it.

If you *deliberately* went out and committed all seven deadly sins, you might be classed as *evil*… and you might still get away with being though merely *very bad*.

Answer (score 12):

You have asked a very pertinent question. Since the strong connotation of 'extreme physical or moral wickedness' has already been established by a senior member in the earlier comments, I shall not go further with the idea that the word 'evil' is employed *very sparingly* by native speakers because they think it ought to be used only for extremely dire situations; but I should like to highlight two other aspects that might possibly lead to its avoidance by native English speakers.

(1) **Strong religious connotations**:

Most religions are founded on the fundamental opposition between Good and Evil. Since the word 'evil' thus has strong religious connotations, many native speakers might hesitate to use it in everyday situations, not least because the ordinary human cruelties, although tragic and very unfortunate, cannot really be equated with Evil on a cosmic scale.

Recommended reading: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_and_evil

(2) **Modern liberal attitude to human behavior**:

With the development of modern psychology and the behavioral sciences, there is a more scientifically liberal (or liberally scientific) approach to human behavior. After studying a huge number of aberrant cases, modern psychology, taken together with sociology, history and evolutionary biology, has taught us not to simply condemn an action as 'evil', but to place a greater emphasis on recognizing humankind's innate propensity for violent behavior, which is explained by our evolutionary descent from amoral, competitively violent animals, and proved by mankind's long history of crimes, wars and conflicts.

Thus many actions that would have been considered 'evil' in earlier centuries have now been reviewed and re-understood by socially liberal individuals and scientifically progressive fields of knowledge as either mentally ill, amoral (a word used by OP which implies a lack of moral awareness), callously selfish or at worst perversely immoral -- did something bad on purpose despite being well aware of the moral implications -- with several explanatory adjectives like callous, selfish, hateful and cruel: none of which is truly 'evil' in the classical or theological sense of the term because the darkest deeds of human beings can now be explained satisfactorily by either evolutionary biology or modern psychology.

In short, whatever human action you might describe as 'evil' can be explained by somebody based on territorial expansionism & competition for resources; sex drive; psychological insecurity or outright insanity; innate biological aggression (read testosterone); or the very dangerous *quest for grandeur* that motivated Alexander, Napoleon and Adolph. What is truly evil? NOTHING, in the modern sense: it is just the human behaving like the innate animal. You might say

> The lion is a cruel beast

but would you say

> The lion is an *evil* beast?

At its worst, the human being is not humane, but is like the lion only.

**In this context, many socially progressive individuals would avoid using the word 'evil' as an old-fashioned, outdated conceptual construction.** Nor is there a need to use 'evil' when you have perfectly adequate words like amoral, perverse, hateful, callous, selfish and cruel!

Read: *[On Evil. Is there such a thing or force as evil? Or just bad deeds? -- from Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/rethinking-men/201608/evil)*

---

Note: the two links provided here (to articles in Wikipedia and Psychology Today websites) are only meant to reflect the overall philosophical approach to good and evil from religious and psychological perspectives; I have not used any material from either source to construct this answer, which is entirely my own written work.

Comment: @EnglishStudent I made a minor edit to your post to improve flow. Feel free to roll back, of course.

Comment: @Dan Bron thank you -- in fact I had deliberately written *'Lion is'* to echo the way non-native speakers often say it, but if you think 'the lion' improves flow, the edit is most welcome!

Comment: @Mari-louA then I shall edit and attribute generically to 'a senior member in earlier comments'. As we know, comments can disappear any time. But I don't want to use the idea without any attribution.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen thanks for the useful edits: I am keeping most of them but please permit me to revert to 'Alexander, Napoleon and Adolph' [misspelling deliberate] without the links to Wikipedia. Why? Because some things are more effective when left subtle. All your other edits are just fine!

Comment: @Ken C - your suggested edit was very pertinent but you unknowingly replaced the text of my answer with the text of your excellent explanation. You are of course right in pointing out the inaccuracy, and I have removed the reference to both 'Judeo-Christian tradition' and the Abrahamic religions because I am from India and not at all knowledgeable about these topics. Thanks for pointing out the error!

Comment: I like this answer; neverthless you might mention that _consequences_ can be evil.

Comment: @Spencer when we say that consequences can be evil, the word 'evil' means 'very bad', which is one of the meanings of the word. OP is not really asking what is the meaning of evil, but *why* native speakers avoid the term. That is why I have not mentioned consequences, but tried to explain that by its own connotations 'evil' itself has become a frame of reference that many persons do not prefer to use in ordinary conversation.

Comment: I agree, Evil is meaningless because it is so poorly defined and generally requires context.  It's one of those "I know it when I see it" words that nobody can quite pin down.